# Customize eshell redirection to buffer

Tags: customize, eshell

In eshell I can redirect the output of a command (`foo`) to a buffer (`bar`) by inputting:

`foo > #<buffer bar>`

I want to customize this syntax the following way:

`foo > #bar`

Is it possible to customize it? How?

**Details**
emacs version: `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.10) of 2017-09-20 on c1bm.rdu2.centos.org`

Comment: Note that also `foo > #<bar>` works. You do not need the word `buffer`. Don't know if that is still too much for you. Works for me on cygwin emacs 26.1.

Comment: @Tobias I tried this on my emacs and I get the error `Eshell does not support input redirection`. I had a look on the eshell manual and it mentions that this command should work.

Comment: Please add version info (`emacs-version`). Does `foo > #<bar>` also fail with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @Tobias, I have just added. Please, see my question. Yes, it also fails with `emacs -Q`, as well as with `emacs --no-window-system`.

Comment: Rather old version... Have you already tried `foo >>> #<bar>`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. Also does not work.

Answer (score 5):

To redirect to a buffer, use `#<buffer buffer-name>`, since Emacs 24.4, you can also use the shorthand `#<buffer-name>`. For example,

```
echo hello >>> #<buffer *scratch*>
echo world >>> #<*scratch*>
```

It looks like it is possible to customize the syntax via the hook `eshell-parse-argument-hook`, such as supporting `#buffer-name` as well. Here is my attempt,

```
(defun eshell-parse-my-special-reference ()
  (when (and (not eshell-current-argument)
             (not eshell-current-quoted)
             ;; Don't overwrite `eshell-parse-special-reference'
             (not (looking-at "#<\\(\\(buffer\\|process\\)\\s-\\)?"))
             (looking-at "#\\(\\S-+\\)")
             (match-string 1))
    (goto-char (match-end 0)) ;; Go to the end of the match.
    (list 'get-buffer-create (match-string 1))))

(add-hook 'eshell-parse-argument-hook #'eshell-parse-my-special-reference)
```

and the following worked as expected

```
echo foobar >>> #*scratch*
```

Comment: Just as a side note: The corresponding changeset: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/e37da5a4a8055826f0fc1051083495a828509672

Comment: This has a weird side effect. When I type a normal command with arguments, such as `ls -lah`, the eshell will not recognize the command. It prints the message `ls -lah: command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

May not be a direct answer to your problem. But you can use key binding `C-c` `M-b` to insert the buffer name at the point. With fido-mode enabled, these key binding help me easily choose the buffer name from the mini-buffer and insert in the form which eshell understands. See `Useful Keybindings` section of [masteringemacs-mastering-eshell](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/complete-guide-mastering-eshell) for more details.