# How to redirect output from eshell to any open buffer in Emacs?

Tags: buffers, eshell

I have my eshell opened in a *window* and in another *window* I have `*Scratch*` as a open buffer. I want to redirect the output of a command like say `ls` to `*Scratch*`. Is it possible? If yes, then how can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

```
ls >(get-buffer "*scratch*")
```

Or even

```
ls > #<buffer *scratch*>
```

See [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42113/customize-eshell-redirection-to-buffer) for more details.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Just did!  Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you don't even need the word "buffer", `ls > #<*scratch*>` seems to work too.

Comment: @Omar Yes Omar, they have simplified that. (Don't know the version where this was introduced.)

Answer (score 0):

The following answer uses a different approach than was suggested by the original poster.  In this example, we use `shell-command-to-string`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html

The `default-directory` in this example is hard-coded to `"~/"`, which may or may not be the `default-directory` of the `*scratch*` buffer.  We use `let*` (instead of just plain old `let`) so that `shell-command-to-string` respects the hard-coded `default-directory` that was `let*`-bound on the preceding line.  If the `*scratch*` buffer did not already exist, then a new one will be created and its `default-directory` will be `"~/"`.  We go to the bottom of the `*scratch*` buffer just in case `point` was somewhere else.  If the buffer is not already visible, then display it in another window.

To try out this example, type `M-x eval-expression` and paste the snippet into the mini-buffer when prompted and press the return key.

```lisp
(let* ((default-directory "~/")
       (string (shell-command-to-string "ls"))
       (buffer (get-buffer-create "*scratch*")))
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (insert string))
  (unless (get-buffer-window "*scratch*")
    (display-buffer buffer t)))
```